# phpMyAdmin DB Query Joining Tables: ON Always Causes #1064 Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

For the record, I read several posts on this site that addressed similar problems, but I was never able to resolve my problem. After many hours, I'm resigning to asking the kind gurus on this site. Below is my SQL query:

```
SELECT `users`.`User`, `courses`.`course`, `member`.`role` 
FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN `courses`, `member` ON `users`.`ID`=`member`.`user_id` 
WHERE `courses`.`ID`='21';
```

This query works on SQLite. However, with phpMyAdmin I get:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ON `users`.`ID`=`member`.`user_id` WHERE `courses`.`ID`='21'
>   LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

The ON clause always blows up. If I remove the ON clause, I get results. I'm at my wits end trying to figure how to make the ON clause work.

FYI: I'm running on XAMPP for my local host. The member table has two foreign keys user_id and course_id but no single primary key. It's a junction table for the many-to-many relationship between courses and users. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside, SQLite and MariaDB are two different database systems and don't use the same syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you need to include the `join` criteria to both tables since you have 2 foreign keys in `member`:

```
select u.user, c.cource, m.role
from users u
    join member m on u.id = m.user_id
    join courses c on m.course_id = c.id
where c.id = 21
```

In general, you should never use commas in your `from` clause -- use the more standard `join` syntax.